# Why doesn't my program return the correct number?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnalyzingScores
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int count = 0;
    double scoreTotal = 0;
    int index;
    int tests;
    double scoreAverage;
    double highest;
    double lowest;

    //Creates a new Scanner.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Asks the user to enter how many tests they have taken.
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of tests you have taken: ");
    tests = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Creates an array.
    int[] score = new int[tests];

    //Creates a for loop that asks a user to enter their test scores.
    for (index = 0; index < tests; index++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter your test score: ");
      score[index] = keyboard.nextInt();

      scoreTotal += score[index];
    }
    scoreAverage = scoreTotal / score.length;

    System.out.println("You entered " + tests + " scores.");
    System.out.println("The test average is " + scoreAverage);
    System.out.println("Number of scores above or equal to the average is " + getHighest(score));
    System.out.println("Number of scores below the average is " + getLowest(score));
    }

    private static int scoreAverage;

    public static int getHighest(int[] score)
    {
      int aboveAverage = 0;

      for (int index = 1; index < score.length; index++)
      {
        if (score[index] >= scoreAverage)
        {
          aboveAverage++;
        }
      }

      return aboveAverage;
    }

    public static int getLowest(int[] score)
    {
      int belowAverage = 0;

      for (int index = 1; index < score.length; index++)
      {
        if (score[index] < scoreAverage)
        {
          belowAverage++;
        }
      }

      return belowAverage;
    }

}
```

Hi everyone! Right now I have an issue with my code and I can't figure out why. The code is supposed to send back the number of scores that are above or equal to the average and those that are below the average.

Sometimes, though, the code doesn't return the correct number. For example, if I type in 3 test scores that are 100, 90, and 80, the average is 90. It should show that 2 are above/equal to 90 and 1 that is below 90. The problem is, it shows that 0 are below 90. I've tested it out several times and it only seems to happen to belowAverage. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that's because you are starting with `index=1` start with `index=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have answered that the problem is with the indexing in your for loops which should be 0-based, and that is certainly a bug in your code. However, that is *not* the problem.

Within functions `getHighest()` and `getLowest()`, the variable `scoreAverage` refers to the uninitialised class level variable declared just prior to the definition of the functions, viz:

```
private static int scoreAverage;
```

not to the `scoreAverage` declared within function `main()`. The class level variable defaults to 0, and that is why you see no values less than the average.

You can fix your code by removing the declaration of `scoreAverage` in `main()` and modifying the class level declaration to:

```
 private static double scoreAverage;
```

It needs to be a double, not an int, as division returns a floating point type, not an integer.

Alternatively you could use a variable of type double declared within `main()` for the score average, and pass that to the two functions, rather than accessing the class level variable, and this is probably preferable.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int index = 1; index < score.length; index++)
```

Arrays in Java (and most programming languages) use [0-based numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). Your loops should start from `int index = 0`, not `int index = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing of your array should start from 0, not 1, in your `getHighest(int[] score)` and `getLowest(int[] score)` methods. This way you are missing out on your first values entered.

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but it is missing some code to help him.

Answer (score 1):

You are *not* checking the element in the `0`th index in your `getHeighest()` and `getLowest()`. Hence you get *one less* of the value that you expected in either `aboveAverage` or `belowAverage`.

Delete the line

```
private static int scoreAverage;
```

and pass `scoreAverage` to both the functions.

Code:

```
public static int getHighest(int[] score, double scoreAverage)
    {
      int aboveAverage = 0;
      //Index should start from 0 to avoid skipping the first element of the array.
      for (int index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
      {
        if (score[index] >= scoreAverage)
        {
          aboveAverage++;
        }
      }

      return aboveAverage;
    }

    public static int getLowest(int[] score, double scoreAverage)
    {
      int belowAverage = 0;
      //Here also, index should start from 0.
      for (int index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
      {
        if (score[index] < scoreAverage)
        {
          belowAverage++;
        }
      }

      return belowAverage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else that helped, but the code is now displaying that there are 3 above/equal to the average.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, your for-loops should start at index 0:

```
for (int index = 0; index < scrore.length; index++)
```

But there's also another problem with your code in that you declare two variables named scoreAverage: one in the main method:
 `double scoreAverage;`
and another time a little below the main method as a static field:
`private static int scoreAverage`;

So there's only one change that you need to do:

```
private static double scoreAverage;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
int count = 0;
double scoreTotal = 0;
int index;
int tests;
//double scoreAverage; <--- remove that
double highest;
double lowest; ...
```

And your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

The methods that you are calling: getHighest() and getLowest() don't have the correct scoreAverage variable. In the code of that methods the scoreAverage variable equals 0. So you can do this:

```
public static int getHighest(int[] score, double scoreAverage)
    {
      int aboveAverage = 0;

      for (int index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
      {
        if (score[index] >= scoreAverage)
        {
          aboveAverage++;
        }
      }

      return aboveAverage;
    }

    public static int getLowest(int[] score, double scoreAverage)
    {
      int belowAverage = 0;

      for (int index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
      {
        if (score[index] < scoreAverage)
        {
          belowAverage++;
        }
      }

      return belowAverage;
    }
```